# JavaScript not working in Mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, safari

Ok, so the problem is that JS code that I am using will not work in mobile Safari straight away. Everything works fine in desktop safari, chrome, etc.

In mobile safari (iphone 4 and ipod touch 2nd gen tested) the page is completely blank. BUT if you navigate to another page and then click back, it loads fine!

Could someone tell me what on earth is happening here?

Thanks :)

Here is a link to the site

http://osmithcouk.ipage.com/exposed/index.php

and here is JS code

NOTE I HAVE EDITED THE CODE SINCE RYUUTATSUO RECOMMENDED THAT I DO SO but still not working :(

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

        $(".slidingDiv").hide();
        $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function(){
    $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

And here is the HTML that goes alongside that.

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide"><b><?php include 'headline1.txt'; ?></b></a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
<?php include 'story1.txt'; ?> <a href="#" class="show_hide">Hide story...</a></div>
```

And the CSS for slidingDiv and show_hide.

```
.slidingDiv {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding:20px;
    margin-top:10px;
}

.show_hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Thank you very much for all your help :)

Comment: Can we see the HTML that goes with it?  Can't really tell exactly what you're trying to do with seeing the rest of the page.

Comment: the only thing I see is that you could use another ; towards the end You have });})}) I am saying have this });});}) other than that I dont see anything either

Comment: Thanks, I have added the html and css plus edited the code :) I have also added a link to the site as it is at the minute.

Comment: How about using the latest jQuery 1.6.1 instead of 1.3.2?

Comment: Thanks. Ok I've updated that and still not working.

Comment: try have the `jquery` **js** in ur local hosting some times the request may blocked by local service providers

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is that you have to add query string parameters in order to get it rendered on mobile. For example

```
script src="js/Common.js" type="text/javascript"
```

Should be replaced by

```
script src="js/Common.js?v=1.1" type="text/javascript"
```

and you can also supply version in comments of your js file so that client can come to know that he has latest version of JS files.

Comment: You have to add query string parameters to get what rendered? Each javascript derived from an src attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if this is the proper protocol but I have fixed it myself so thought I would post my answer!

It really is simple, I just moved the JS to below the .CSS. Apparently Safari has a problem rendering jQuery before CSS :s

Answer (score 0):

use

```
jQuery(window).load()
```

instead of

```
jQuery(document).ready()
```

Comment: While this could possibly answer the question, please consider adding an explaination on what causes the problem and why your answer solves it